# When were linguistics departments first established

Tags: history-of-linguistics

Linguistics differs in studying languages from other fields such as English, French and so on, by concentrating on theoretical parts that are shared by all languages.

I wonder when was the first time that linguistics departments were established in major universities, i.e. what time linguistics was considered as a separate field from other individual languages. Were (most) linguistics departments set up in 1950s after Chomsky's work?

Comment: Are you excluding Philology departments?

Comment: No, Philology is not considered. Only linguistics or theoretical linguistics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, before Chomsky. I have a vague recollection that Leonard Bloomfield helped establish an early department with "linguistics" in its name, but I can't find that.  However, note "linguistics" in the titles of some of his professorships, e.g. "Professor of German and Linguistics at the Ohio State University, 1921-1927" ([Leonard Bloomfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Bloomfield#Career)).

I found it. In 1901 the first department of linguistics was established at the U. of California, [History of Berkeley Linguistics](https://lx.berkeley.edu/about/history-berkeley-linguistics).

Comment: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4272

Comment: @Nardog, Thanks for the reference to this discussion on Language Log.  However, I don't find it at all persuasive.  Pullum and others argue that whether the department is called a department of linguistics is irrelevant.  But it's not at all irrelevant!  That is the question that is being asked.

Comment: Neither do I. I just put the link for further reference.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, there were linguistics departments *before* Chomsky all over the world.

Harvard U: 1941

St. Petersburg U (Russia): since 1932 known as the Department of General Linguistics; goes back to 1863, originally known as the Department of Indo-European Comparative Studies.

etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think Ferdinand de Saussure started teaching general linguistics in Geneva circa 1892. Before that, he taught Gothic and Old German in Paris starting in 1881.

Comment: One teacher is not a department however. Linguistics was taught in classics, literature, and philosophy departments before being given its own departments.

Comment: Do you mean that a linguist is not a linguist, because his/her academic environment does not explicitly include a linguistics department?? This does not seem reasonable.

Comment: @ArnaudFournet, It would not be reasonable, but no one said that, or implied it.

Comment: I think a better way to define it would be: Which university first issued degrees in linguistics?